# If statement: Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-3.5

I keep getting an error message in my if statement:

```
 fun someFunction(){
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode = Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) { 
        // Do stuff
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please show the code

Comment: if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode = Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            // proceed and check what the selected image was
            Log.d("RegisterActivity","Photo was selected")

Comment: and also I'm getting this error  Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Boolean was expected
 for the result code and Classifier 'BitmapDrawable' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here
 this error for bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable

Comment: You are missing a `==` here `resultCode = Activity.RESULT_OK`

Comment: Thank you  for your answer do you know how to fix the Classifier 'BitmapDrawable' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here.problem

Comment: @anime_verse you should provide a clear question and example of code for each thing you are having a problem with. This will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: My problem is when I try to use bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable and runs the app I'm getting an error saying that  Classifier 'BitmapDrawable' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here. the code for it was vall bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(content resolver,Uri)
            val bitmapDrawable =  BitmapDrawable
            select_photo_btn_register.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable)

Comment: @anime_verse you should ask a separate question with an example of the code. Similar to how I have edited your question here. You should not ask multiple questions in a single question. Never the less, you need to call that classes constructor like this `BitmapDrawable(<constructor arguments>)` or if it is abstract, then you need some concrete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK`

Comment: Thank you for your answer and do you know how to solve Classifier 'BitmapDrawable' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here this problem